Nonvanishing of Jacquet modules of principal series subquotients
Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over a $p$-adic field $F$. For simplicity, we assume $G$ to be split. Fix a Borel $B=TU$ with its Levi decomposition ($U$ unipotent radical, $T$ maximal torus). For convenience here I identify the notations for algebraic groups with those for $F$-points.
Let $\chi:T\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$ be a character of $T$ and $i_B^G\chi$ be the normalized parabolic induction, so that this is a principal series of $G$. Suppose $\chi$ is regular, i.e. for any element $w$ of the Weyl group $W=W(G,T)$, $w\chi\neq \chi$ (notation: $w\chi(t):=\chi(w^{-1}tw)$ ). In this case one knows that the normalized Jacquet module (not merely semisimplification)
$$(i_B^G\chi)_B\simeq \bigoplus_{w\in W}w\chi.$$
My question is the following. Take a composition factor $\pi$ of $i_B^G\chi$, is it true that $\pi_B$ (normalized Jacquet module) is nonzero?
This seems to be a natural question in a more general setting. By the geometric lemma of Bernstein-Zelevinsky and Casselman, given two parabolic subgroups $P=MN$ and $Q=LV$, $\sigma$ an irreducible smooth representation of $M$, then there is a formula to compute the semisimplification of the Jacquet module $(i_P^G\sigma)_Q$. The general question is that what can we say about semisimplification of the Jacquet modules of the composition series of $i_P^G\sigma$? Do we have any finer statements such as nonvanishing result under some conditions?
Thanks a lot in advance for any help or discussion! (Since I am just a beginner, I apologize in advance if this is quite naive for experts.)

I think it is known that any composition factor of $i_B^G\chi$ can be embedded into potentially another $i_B^G\chi'$, so that by the (first) adjointness the Jacquet module of such a factor is non-zero. Would that work?
